# Add a page with a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I have a plugin that adds a few admin pages, a dashboard widget and a normal widget but I can't figure out how to add a page to the site.

I want to create a permalink that makes wordpress use `myplugin/page.php` which I assume will need to look like:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
MY CONTENT
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Is this possible?

Comment: You can draw a lot of inspiration from the answer from @gmazzap

Comment: Looks good, I will have a look at it as soon as I can.